# How do I make this code snippet actually update within the original "Test_Table"

Tags: sql, database, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am very new to SQL as well as coding in general so I apologize if this question is very rudimentary. I have this code snippet that runs a few simple queries on a pre-existing dataset. When I run the code, it pops up a table with all of the queries executed correctly. However, it doesn't update the data in the table "test_table". Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
WITH RankedData AS (
    SELECT
        *,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY player_id ORDER BY DMY DESC) AS row_num
    FROM TEST_TABLE
)

SELECT
    CASE
        WHEN row_num = 1 THEN game_id
        WHEN row_num >= 1 THEN game_id
        ELSE NULL
    END AS game_id,
    CASE
        WHEN row_num = 1 THEN DMY
        WHEN row_num >= 1 THEN DMY
        ELSE NULL
    END AS date,
    player_id,
    CASE
        WHEN row_num = 1 THEN
            AVG(stat) OVER (PARTITION BY player_id ORDER BY row_num ROWS BETWEEN 1 FOLLOWING AND 2 FOLLOWING)
        WHEN row_num >= 1 THEN
            AVG(stat) OVER (PARTITION BY player_id ORDER BY row_num ROWS BETWEEN 1 FOLLOWING AND 2 FOLLOWING)
        ELSE NULL
    END AS stat
FROM RankedData
ORDER BY player_id, row_num
```

When this code is executed, it pops up a new table on the bottom of the worksheet that does everything correctly. However, it does not actually update the original Test_Table.

Answer (score 0):

As you are unfamiliar with SQL I suggest you take steps to ensure you have a copy of any table you try to update ("just in case"). Also note the following is untested and not guaranteed - so proceed with due caution.

```
WITH RankedData AS (
    SELECT
        *,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY player_id ORDER BY DMY DESC) AS row_num
    FROM TEST_TABLE
)
UPDATE TEST_TABLE
SET
    game_id = (
        CASE
            WHEN row_num = 1 THEN game_id
            WHEN row_num >= 1 THEN game_id
            ELSE NULL
        END
    ),
    date = (
        CASE
            WHEN row_num = 1 THEN DMY
            WHEN row_num >= 1 THEN DMY
            ELSE NULL
        END
    ),
    stat = (
        CASE
            WHEN row_num = 1 THEN AVG(stat) OVER (PARTITION BY player_id ORDER BY row_num ROWS BETWEEN 1 FOLLOWING AND 2 FOLLOWING)
            WHEN row_num >= 1 THEN AVG(stat) OVER (PARTITION BY player_id ORDER BY row_num ROWS BETWEEN 1 FOLLOWING AND 2 FOLLOWING)
            ELSE NULL
        END
    )
FROM RankedData
WHERE TEST_TABLE.player_id = RankedData.player_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

The table at the bottom, is just a display of the results. it is not "a table" to create a table you need to [UPDATE](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/update) or [INSERT](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/insert) or [CREATE](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/create-table#create-table-as-select-also-referred-to-as-ctas) (CTAS) tables

the update would look like:

```
UPDATE TEST_TABLE
  SET game_id = s.game_id, 
    date = s.date,
    stat = stat
  FROM (
        WITH RankedData AS (
            SELECT
                *,
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY player_id ORDER BY DMY DESC) AS row_num
            FROM TEST_TABLE
        )

        SELECT
            CASE
                WHEN row_num = 1 THEN game_id
                WHEN row_num >= 1 THEN game_id
                ELSE NULL
            END AS game_id,
            CASE
                WHEN row_num = 1 THEN DMY
                WHEN row_num >= 1 THEN DMY
                ELSE NULL
            END AS date,
            player_id,
            CASE
                WHEN row_num = 1 THEN
                    AVG(stat) OVER (PARTITION BY player_id ORDER BY row_num ROWS BETWEEN 1 FOLLOWING AND 2 FOLLOWING)
                WHEN row_num >= 1 THEN
                    AVG(stat) OVER (PARTITION BY player_id ORDER BY row_num ROWS BETWEEN 1 FOLLOWING AND 2 FOLLOWING)
                ELSE NULL
            END AS stat
        FROM RankedData
  ) as s
WHERE TEST_TABLE.player_id = s.player_id
```

this is like this, as the CTE is a binding object (in snowflake) with the SELECT thus both go into the sub-select.

Now your `stat` CASE the THEN's are the same and the second WHEN covers the first, and given row number starts at 1, which means your three cases can be thrown away:

so your SQL appears to be the same as:

```
SELECT
    game_id,
    DMY AS date,
    player_id,
    AVG(stat) OVER (PARTITION BY player_id ORDER BY DMY DESC ROWS BETWEEN 1 FOLLOWING AND 2 FOLLOWING) as stat
FROM TEST_TABLE
ORDER BY player_id, DMY DESC
```

albeit, the row_number version will have stability within itself, but given you are using the results to update a table the ORDER BY is meaningless.

So you could just use:

```
UPDATE TEST_TABLE
  SET game_id = s.game_id, 
    date = s.date,
    stat = stat
  FROM (
    SELECT
        game_id,
        DMY AS date,
        player_id,
        AVG(stat) OVER (PARTITION BY player_id ORDER BY DMY DESC ROWS BETWEEN 1 FOLLOWING AND 2 FOLLOWING) as stat
    FROM TEST_TABLE
  ) as s
WHERE TEST_TABLE.player_id = s.player_id
```